# Rule Editor Syntax Error in catia formula

Tags: formula, catia

I try an example About the Rule Editor from CATIA V5 R28.

After "Apply" it appears:

Syntax Error line 1 :

Parameter sketch.4/radius  cannot be used in this context.

Can you help me ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get help, you have to post more than the error message. First try to explain what you want to accomplish and how you trying to do that. An Example code could be also helpful.

You are using EKL language in Catia so try to learn ho to use it.

http://catiadoc.free.fr/online/kwrug_C2/kwrugat5000.htm